# autocomplete to avoid tab operation for textbox

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am using Autocomlete to show the list of location which come from database. User get the list as expected. but instate selecting from list user just click on the tab button and control going to next button. I want to avoid TAB operation here.Any suggestion how i will do that .
Here is my function :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        src = 'LocationHandler.ashx';

        $('#txtLocationName').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: src,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term: request.term,
                        type: $("#ddlDivision1").val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        Object.keys = Object.keys || function (o, k, r) { r = []; for (k in o) r.hasOwnProperty.call(o, k) && r.push(k); return r }
                           if (Object.keys(data).length == 0) {
                            $('#txtLocationName').val('');
                            alert('Location must be selected from the options.');
                        }

                        response(data);
 }
                    });
            },
                min_length: 3,
            delay: 300
        });
        });
```

My Handler class looks like

```
public class LocationHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
      string type = context.Request["type"] ?? "";
    //  type = "FM";
        List<string> listLocationNames = new List<string>();
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EGLFormsDB"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spIARLocationNames", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@term",
                Value = term
            });
             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@locType",
                Value = type
            });
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                listLocationNames.Add(rdr["Name"].ToString());
            }
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listLocationNames));
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solve this.

```
 $("#txtLocationName").keydown(function (evt) {
            var keyCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
            if (keyCode == 9) {
                //evt.preventDefault();
                //alert("TAB not allowed111111. Please select business unit number or name  from  Search box. ");
                var textloc = $("#txtLocationName").val();
                var specialChars = "{"

                if (textloc.indexOf("{") >= 0) {
                    //no need to do anything
                }
                else {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    alert("TAB not allowed. Please select business unit number or name  from  Search box. ");
                }

            }

            if (evt.key === "Tab")

            {
              var textloc = $("#txtLocationName").val();
                var specialChars = "{"

                if (textloc.indexOf("{") >= 0) {
                    //no need to do anything
                }
                else {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    alert("TAB not allowed. Please select business unit number or name  from  Search box. ");
                }

            }
               });
```